How to set up this problem geometrically? (Hatcher AT Page 131 Problem 3)
I'm attempting to go through all of Hatcher's problems on homology. I was able to do 1, 2, 4, and 5 so far, but I don't know what he's asking for geometrically in 3. I see this thread (Hatcher algebraic Topology $\Delta$-complex) but I wouldn't mind a drawing for $\mathbb S^1$:

Construct a $\Delta$--complex structure on $\mathbb R P^n$ as a quotient of a $\Delta$--complex structure on $\mathbb S^n$ having vertices the two vectors of length $1$ along each coordinate axis in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

Let's look at the unit circle $\mathbb S^1$, and attempt to construct Hatcher's $\Delta$--complex on it. Would this be the correct way of setting up the problem in this dimension?

However, I don't know how or where to draw my simplices, since this shape has four sides and vertices. Also, I don't know how the identification maps would work on this. Hatcher has a sketch of $\mathbb R P^2$ here:

but I don't know what I'm meant to do: should I draw the simplicial complex somehow and then choose which vertices and sides I want to identify? Am I setting up and doing the problem wrong? I think that I might be supposed to make the origin one of the vertices, and construct two simplices from it, but I'm not sure. Any visual or computational help would be welcome for $\mathbb S^1$. Once I have it worked out concretely in one dimension, I wouldn't mind trying to generalize it up to $\mathbb S^n$ on my own.

First try the $S^n$ part. The complex for $S^n$ should have $2^n$ top-dimensional simplices, one in each orthant. Then keep in mind that $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is the quotient of $S^n$ by $x \sim -x$.
